# How to override the message of the custom validation rule in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, validationrules

I am developing a Laravel application. What I am doing in my application is that I am trying to override the custom validation rule message.

I have validation rules like this in the request class:

```
[
    'name'=> [ 'required' ],
    'age' => [ 'required', new OverAge() ],
];
```

Normally, we override the error message of the rules like this:

```
return [
    'title.required' => 'A title is required',
    'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
];
```

But how can I do that to the custom validation rule class?

Comment: have you tried using `age.over_age` ?

Comment: you can create a custom rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: I believe this is a bug. Feel free to submit the PR to laravel/framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot simply overwrite it with the custom messages of the request. If you take a look at the `Validator` class:

```
/**
 * Validate an attribute using a custom rule object.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule  $rule
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateUsingCustomRule($attribute, $value, $rule)
{
    if (! $rule->passes($attribute, $value)) {
        $this->failedRules[$attribute][get_class($rule)] = [];

        $this->messages->add($attribute, $this->makeReplacements(
            $rule->message(), $attribute, get_class($rule), []
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's simply adding the `$rule->message()` directly to the message bag.

However, you can add a parameter for the message in your custom rule's class:

```
public function __construct(string $message = null)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}
```

Then in your message function:

```
public function message()
{
    return $this->message ?: 'Default message';
}
```

And finally in your rules:

```
'age' => ['required', new OverAge('Overwritten message')];
```

Comment: just curious, why use `?:` over `??`

Comment: @DerekPollard `??` only checks if it's not null and isset. Doesn't check if the it's positive. But both works.

Answer (score 5):

Working with Laravel 9, overriding the message is supported, but you must supply the FQDN for the validation class. So your `OverAge` custom message may look like this:

```
return [
    'age.required' => 'An age is required',
    'age.App\\Rules\\OverAge'  => 'The age must be less than 65',
];
```

You may also want to support place-holders for the message, so the `65` can be replaced by something like `:max-age`. Many ways to do that are published, none of which look particularly clean.

Comment: If anybody needs this, this answer worked for me.